# Android Audio Recorder enabled by NFC

Tags: android, audio, nfc, record

I’m really new in java programming. I’m trying to build an android application that will be enabled by NFC, record sound (during sleep) continuously (in separated files of 1-2 minutes length and then start a new recording file), uploading each one of them (right after it’s recorded) on a server and then deleting them from the phone. Also I want to add a UTC timestamp to every file , to be able to synchronize these sounds recordings with other signals, on the same graph.
I’ve found this (http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.gr/2012/06/voice-recording-in-android.html) open source app, which records audio. I need to make it to : 
1.  Start while I put the phone on the NFC
2.  Record files with 1-2 minutes max length
3.  Upload each one on the server and then delete it  from the phone
4.  Add UTC timestamps
Could you help me with any of these? Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not very complicated.
At first you should know which type of NFC tag you will process in your app.
Here is pretty nice guide how use NFC in Android: [Android: NFC](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html)

When your information from NFC tag already parsed, just start recording using MediaRecorder class:
[Android: MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)

Comment: Thanks!As I said,I'm new in Java,could you suggest me a page which  could have free java lessons and excersises?Should I also have lessons for android?